# KnockoutJS visible binding nested

Tags: knockout.js, binding, visible

I have a form with a dropdown having values 'Current' and 'Future'. When user selects either of the options divs are made visible using knockout visible binding and subscribing to dropdown selection. This part is working fine.
Now within that view which we make visible, upon selection of chkGroup (checkbox), I need to make visible another div i.e. data-bind="visible: showchkGroupSelected". So I am using similar code to subscribe to that checkbox click. But evidentally it is not working. Please advise. 
HTML code:

```
    <div class="row row-content">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <h4>Select Planning</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">
        <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="requestType" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Planning Type</label>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <select style="width:350px" class="input-md" data-bind="options:  DayRequests, value: SelectedRequestType,  optionsCaption: 'Select current / future'"></select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<!--Current -->

<div class="container-fluid" data-bind="visible: ShowCurrent">
    <!-- ko with: CurrentVM -->
    <h4>Current Day Request</h4>
    <div class="row row-content">

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">
            <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-2">

                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked:chkTownHall">Townhall(s)</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked:chkSales">Sales Meeting</label>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-2">

                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked:chkGroups">Groups</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked:chkConference">Conference</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>

        </div>

    </div>
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>
<!--future-->
<div class="container-fluid" data-bind="visible: ShowFuture">
    <!-- ko with: FutureVM -->

    <h4>Future Day Request</h4>
    <div class="row row-content">

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">
            <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-2">

                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked:chkTownHallF">Townhall(s)</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked:chkSalesF">Sales Meeting</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-2">

                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked:chkGroupsF">Groups</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked:chkConferenceF">Conference</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>
<!--Group Selected -->
<div class="row row-content" data-bind="visible: showchkGroupSelected">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <h4>Group Details</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">
        <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="trainingName" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name of Training</label>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="value:GroupName">
                </div>
                <label for="CrossFunc" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Group has functions?</label>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <label class="form-check-inline">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" data-bind="checked:optFunction"  id="optFunctionYes" value="1"> Yes

                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" data-bind="checked:optFunction" id="optFunctionNo" value="0"> No
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the script:

```
     <script>
        var MainViewModel = function () {
            var self = this;
            self.DayRequests = ko.observableArray(['Current', 'Future']);
            self.ShowCurrent = ko.observable(false);
            self.ShowFuture = ko.observable(false);
            self.FutureVM = ko.observable();
            self.CurrentVM = ko.observable();
            self.SelectedRequestType = ko.observable();
            self.SelectedRequestType.subscribe(function (requestTypeVal) {
                if (requestTypeVal == 'Current') {
                    self.ShowCurrent(true);
                    self.ShowFuture(false);
                    self.CurrentVM(new planViewModel());
                }
                else if (requestTypeVal == 'Future') {
                    self.FutureVM(new planViewModel());
                    self.ShowFuture(true);
                    self.ShowCurrent(false);
                }
            });
            //can't figure out the following piece////////
            self.GroupVM = ko.observable();
            self.showchkGroupSelected = ko.observable(false);
            self.chkGroups.subscribe(function (value) {
                if (value == true)
                {
                    self.showchkGroupSelected(true);
                    self.GroupVM(new CurrGroupVM());
                }
                else {
                    self.showchkGroupSelected(false);
                }
            });
        }
        var CurrGroupVM = function () {
            var self = this;
            self.optFunction = ko.observable(false);
            self.GroupName = ko.observable(false);
        }
        //////////////////
        var planViewModel = function () {
            var self = this;
            self.chkTownHall = ko.observable(false);
            self.chkSales = ko.observable(false);
            self.chkGroups = ko.observable(false);
            self.chkConference = ko.observable(false);
            self.chkTownHallF = ko.observable(false);
            self.chkConferenceF = ko.observable(false);
            self.chkGroupsF = ko.observable(false);
            self.chkSalesF = ko.observable(false);
        };

        ko.applyBindings(new MainViewModel());
    </script>
```

Comment: I can't see `chkGroups` defined as an observable inside  `MainViewModel` that you are subscribing. Please take a look at your console log tools on the browser  to see if you are getting any erorrs

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined. I defined chkGroups inside planViewModel

Comment: If I put chkGroups inside the MainViewModel, then I get error message: chkGroups is not defined AND GroupName is not defined

Answer (score 0):

`GroupName` & `optFunction` are part of `CurrGroupVM`. 
You need to wrap them with `GroupVM` as

```
<!-- ko with: GroupVM-->
    ....HTML elements....
<!-- /ko -->
```

or
inline binding :

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" data-bind="with:GroupVM">`
    ....HTML elements....
 </form>
```

view:

```
.....

  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">
      <!-- ko with: GroupVM -->
        <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
             <div class="form-group">
                <label for="trainingName" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name of Training</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="value:GroupName">
                    </div>
                    <label for="CrossFunc" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Group has functions?</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <label class="form-check-inline">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" data-bind="checked:optFunction"  id="optFunctionYes" value="1"> Yes

                            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" data-bind="checked:optFunction" id="optFunctionNo" value="0"> No
                        </label>
                   </div>
              </div>
         </form>
       <!-- /ko -->
    </div>
```

Comment: Added <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" data-bind="with:GroupVM">. But it did not resolve the issue of making visible showchkGroupSelected div. Also, I am still getting error-Message: chkGroups is not defined. Please guide!

Comment: The functionality is that on checking chkGroup, I subscribe to it and the corresponding div should display ( data-bind="visible: showchkGroupSelected"). The jsfiddle is not displaying error but at the same time not giving the functionality on chkGroup check. However, when I use the same code in html and run it in Chrome, in developer tools it gives - Message: chkGroups is not defined